# Create divisors dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a function that takes three parameters: `divisors` (a list), `lower`, and `upper`, where `upper >= lower`. I want the function to return a dictionary where the keys are the divisors and its values are the list of numbers between the range (lower and upper) that are divisible by the corresponding divisor.

Here is my initial try:

```py
def create_divisors_dict(divisors, lower, upper):
    list = []
    dict = {}
    for i in range(len(divisors)):
        for j in range(lower, upper + 1):
            if j % divisors[i] == 0:
                list.append(j)
                dict[i] = list
            else:
                dict[i] = []
    
    return dict

print(create_divisors_dict([1, 2, 5], 2, 4))
```

The intended output is:

```py
{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [2, 4], 5: []}
```

However, I keep getting some weird output, and this is the closest that I got with my code shown above:

```
{1: [2, 3, 4, 2, 4], 2: [2, 3, 4, 2, 4], 5: []}
```

Can someone please help me and tell me where the issue is or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't name things `list` and `dict` -- it overwrites builtin functions.

Comment: That code doesn't create the output that you say it does.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yep, sorry for that, my console got stuck for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is just another alternative, constructed on the code you posted:

```py
def create_divisors_dict(divisors, lower, upper):
    d = {}
    for divisor in divisors:
        d[divisor] = []
        for n in range(lower, upper + 1):
            if n % divisor == 0:
                d[divisor].append(n)

    return d
```

Or using a bit of list comprehension:

```py
def create_divisors_dict(divisors, lower, upper):
    d = {}
    for divisor in divisors:
        d[divisor] = [n for n in range(lower, upper + 1) if n % divisor == 0]

    return d
```

Or even combining dictionary and list comprehensions:

```py
def create_divisors_dict(divisors, lower, upper):
    return {d: [n for n in range(lower, upper + 1) if n % d == 0] for d in divisors}
```

Where any of them will result in:

```py
print(create_divisors_dict([1, 2, 5], 2, 4))

{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [2, 4], 5: []}
```

Comment: Sure! It is. The answer is just an alternative built above what OP already understood. That's why I upvoted your answer BTW. You posted the best and most pythonic approach IMHO.

Comment: I guess we thought about the same thing at the same time. lol

Comment: A few seconds away I considered joking "Now with the list comp solution you're just two steps away from mine". And now it's just one.

Comment: Yep. Same ideas but a little different in implementation. Anyway, yours is still the one I would choose.

Comment: I also prefer mine, but I admit it's slightly tricky. Though that's one reason I like it :-). But yours is probably better at least for beginners.

Comment: @Ahmed, you can mark one of the answers as accepted since you are the author of that question.

Answer (score 1):

@Carci already explained one of your bugs, another is that you reset `dict[i] = []` for no good reason, and a third is that you don't use the divisors but their indices as the result keys (wouldn't have happened if you did normal iteration over the divisors).

Anyway, here's a short and efficient solution:

```
def create_divisors_dict(divisors, lower, upper):
    return {d: [*range(lower + -lower % d, upper + 1, d)]
            for d in divisors}
```

Or with a different expression for the first multiple in the range:

```
def create_divisors_dict(divisors, lower, upper):
    return {d: [*range(-(-lower // d) * d, upper + 1, d)]
            for d in divisors}
```